# Возможно ли получить разрешение больше чем 1920х1200 на openbsd в qemu ( virt-manager)?

Tags: виртуальная-машина, qemu, openbsd

Пробовал virtio, qxl там получается ещё меньше чем в VGA,  проверял максимальное разрешение с помощью xrandr